# Auto-generated javascript code, is it valid?

Tags: javascript

I have auto-generated js code containing a few files which I'm unable to run now. It looks like this:

```
//...........
var Something(https:SomethingElse) = require('some-namespace-(https://some/web-url/com)');

//..............
```

It've obfucated it. I wonder, is that valid javascript code? If yes, what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Looks like something went wrong in the obfuscation process.

Comment: @DaveNewton it just looks like.

Comment: Where was this auto-generated from? What did you use to obfuscate it? Do you still have the unobfuscated source?

Comment: @OmarShehata, what did you eat this morning? What's your salary? What's your favourite colour? How many times do you brush your teeth per day? Do you like Jeremy S? These questions are very relevant to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  A valid JavaScript identifier can't have colons or parentheses in it like `Something(https:SomethingElse)` does.  I'm not sure about whether what it's passing to the `require` function is valid or not though.  I've never used node.js, at least that's what I think it's from.